# SQL merge different table data counts

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

Below is my query to get some data for dashboard screen.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as occupied_rooms FROM rooms  where available='N' ;
SELECT COUNT(*) as checkedIn_guests FROM booking where checkout_time='' ;
SELECT COUNT(*) as available_rooms FROM rooms  where available='Y' ;
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_guest FROM booking;
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_booking FROM booking;
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_staff FROM employee;
```

It produce output as show in above[image: Current output]

How ever I want the output like given above image.[image: required output]

Comment: `UNION` them, though formatting should be done at the presentation (not DB) layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a UNION for build  single table result with each result in a row

```
SELECT 'occupied_rooms', COUNT(*) count
FROM rooms  
where available='N'
UNION 
SELECT  'checkedIn_guests',  COUNT(*) 
FROM booking 
where checkout_time='' 
UNION 
SELECT 'available_rooms', COUNT(*) 
FROM rooms  
where available='Y' 
UNION 
SELECT 'total_guest', COUNT(*)
FROM booking
UNION 
SELECT 'total_booking', COUNT(*) 
FROM booking
UNION 
SELECT 'total_staff', COUNT(*) 
FROM employee;
```

Comment: Why use `UNION`, which will do an additional sort distinct, when you already know all the rows will be distinct? Use `UNION ALL` instead, which do no additional work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `union all`

```
SELECT 'occupied_rooms' as which, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM rooms where available = 'N'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'checkedIn_guests', COUNT(*) FROM booking where checkout_time = ''
UNION ALL
SELECT 'available_rooms', COUNT(*) FROM rooms where available = 'Y' ;
UNION ALL
SELECT 'total_guest', COUNT(*) FROM booking;
UNION ALL
SELECT 'total_booking', COUNT(*) FROM booking;
UNION ALL
SELECT 'total_staff', COUNT(*) FROM employee;
```

You could make the query a bit more efficient by combining the queries that reference the same table.  But the overall structure would be essentially the same.